# TextInputLayout's word counter disapear when text goes second Line in MultiAutoCompletetTextView in android material design

Tags: android

I have an form in which use can put some details. All works but when user goes to put details like description of service or use feedback description in last editText which have multiLine EditText (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) text/word counter disappear when text goes to next line(second or third).

Here is before and after sceenshot.

Before goes to second line

[image]

After user goes to second line

[image]

and here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:title="Contact us"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/ToolbarTitleColor"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.example.admin.venturedreamsdesign.Contact">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/TextInputName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Your Name (required)"
                        android:singleLine="true" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/TextInputEmail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Your Email (required)"
                        android:singleLine="true" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/TextInputSubject"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Subject"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:counterEnabled="true"
                    app:counterMaxLength="250"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:hint="Your Message (required)" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: please check my ans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `LinearLayout` height with `wrap_content` and add missing Constraints,   check below code this may help you

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:title="Contact us"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/ToolbarTitleColor"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.example.admin.venturedreamsdesign.Contact">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="344dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/TextInputName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Your Name (required)"
                        android:singleLine="true" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/TextInputEmail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Your Email (required)"
                        android:singleLine="true" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/TextInputSubject"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Subject"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:counterEnabled="true"
                    app:counterMaxLength="250"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp">

                    <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:hint="Your Message (required)" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

screenshot

[image]

Comment: okay. i think my device have bugs like this because i am on custom rom.

Comment: what do you mean **character counter not show realtime text** I posted screenshot also

Comment: thanks sir. you fixed my problem.i have one question . sir can you tell me what i am doing wrong???

Comment: add margin to message textinput also check updated code .

Comment: if this post helps to resolve your error then you may mark as accept answer like https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/376420

Answer (score -1):

Try this use this  `android:maxLines="10"` property display.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="250"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:hint="Your Message (required)" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: sir your code works. i found animation problem.like i can see counter when i  reach max length and on erasing the text it will show counter . i think counter only display when you reach maxLength.what you say sir??

Comment: i also faced that counter not display realtime text .

Comment: please give more information. i have not faced any issue which you have mention above.

Comment: okay. when i was reached to last character of current line(first line) counter display with inputed character text like (48 In my case ).but when i typed another text then text will goes to next line and counter disappear. and it will character once i reach to maxLength and erasing all the text .same problem happend when i again do this.